# _StreamHandlerTransformer<A, B> is not a subtype of type StreamTransformer<C, B> when C extends A

Tags: flutter, dart

**Error message:**

```
'_StreamHandlerTransformer<UserEntity, Either<Failure, UserEntity>>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<UserModel, Either<Failure, UserEntity>>' of 'streamTransformer'
```

**UserEntity / UserModel**

```
  class UserModel extends UserEntity {}
```

**Problem code:**

```
  Stream<Either<Failure, T>> transform(_Usecase<Stream<T>> usecase) async* {
    yield* usecase().transform(
      StreamTransformer<T, Either<Failure, T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (data, sink) {
          sink.add(Right(data));
        },
        handleError: (e, _, sink) {
          sink.add(Left(Failure(message: '$e')));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Code explained**

`Stream<Either<IFailure, UserEntity>> transform` accepts function `_Usecase<Stream<UserModel>> usecase` and tries to transform but fails because type doesn't match error above.

Why am I getting this error when `UserModel extends UserEntity`? And how do I fix it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by extending generic

```
  Stream<Either<Failure, T>> transform<M extends T>(
    _Usecase<Stream<M>> usecase,
  ) async* {
    yield* usecase().transform(
      StreamTransformer<M, Either<Failure, T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (data, sink) {
          sink.add(Right(data));
        },
        handleError: (e, _, sink) {
          sink.add(Left(Failure(message: '$e')));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```